# How do I install it on my notebook? it has no CD

Tags: installation, live-usb

I don´t have a CD drive on my Asus notebook, and the installation file doesn't work when I try to install from a USB drive.

Comment: more information please?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work when I try to install from a USB drive.'? Does it boot? Does it provide an install option?

Comment: please let us know the version of Ubuntu that you are trying to install with your USB drive. You can also explain how you created your Ubuntu Live USB

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to re-create your USB drive:

1. download an Ubuntu version from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (you can try both 12.04 and 13.04)
2. reformat your USB drive to FAT32
3. create the bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive:

   - [from a Ubuntu PC](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) ( I recommended this solution )
   - or [from a Windows PC](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
4. configure your computer to boot from USB flash drive and boot from it.

[Well the detailed instructions are here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running Windows at the moment, I would recommend downloading unetbootin.

It can do everything for you. All you need to do is select a linux distro (or, alternatively, an iso you have already downloaded), and the USB drive you wish to use, and it will automatically download the live bootable iso (if you didn't already have one) and write it to your drive. Then you just reboot, making sure you have USB boot priority, and install from the live boot.